# it show me error expected primary expression before ';' token

Tags: c++, winapi

i get the error in wc.lpfnWndProc   = WNDPROC;

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE hPrevinstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShot)
    {
        WNDCLASSEX wc;
        HWND hwnd;
        MSG msg;

        wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
        wc.style         = 0;
        wc.lpfnWndProc   = WNDPROC;
        wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
        wc.hInstance     = hinstance;
        wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1);
        wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
        wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

        if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "windows registration failed!", "error",
                        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you defined `WNDPROC` as? The RHS of `wc.lpfnWndProc =` must be the name of a function ***you have already declared/defined***.

Comment: If you are just using what `Windows.h` has defined for `WNDPROC` then that's just wrong! `WNDPROC` there is the definition of what you function should look like.

Comment: WNDPROC is a data type, not an expression.  You define a function with the signature `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`, then the assignment would be: `wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;`  The question was perhaps too hastily closed in my opinion - better luck next time.  Always better to post the verbatim error log rather than paraphrasing it.

Comment: @Clifford - I cannot vote to reopen! But I hope the brief answer I gave is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your own WNDPROC function, along these lines …

```
//typedef LRESULT (CALLBACK* WNDPROC)(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);//from "WinUser.h"
LRESULT CALLBACK MyWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (uMsg == 123456) { // Probably best not to use this actual number!
        // Put some code here to handle specific values of uMsg ...
    }
    //
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam); // Otherwise, call the default!
}
```

Then you can put (in your main program): `wc.lpfnWndProc = MyWindowProc;`